# Importing .sql file inside Docker image

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a problem importing .sql file inside Docker image (official MySQL image). I'm relatively new to both of them, but this is what I accomplished so far:

1. When I try to import file from inside the Docker image I use:
   `'USE DATABASE test;'` and then `source data.aktualnosci.sql`, but using this path and other various relative paths to Docker volume folder (where I can store files) just results in `Failed to open file`.
2. When I do this outside the image in the folder where the file is located: `docker exec -i some-mysql mysql -uroot -pmy-secret-pw data < data.aktualnosci.sql` it results in `ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 21: Table 'data.aktualnosci' doesn't exist`.
3. When I create that table then use command from the 1st bullet point don't throw any errors, but I get this error instead: `ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 23: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`
4. And when I create table and put inside i.e. two random columns then there are no errors, but table is empty.

So it's like each time I get ahead there is another problem. I have like 40 tables to import - I'm sure there is a way to do it smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

Acording to [MySQL image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/):

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

So if you wish to initialize your container with SQL data it's as simple as:

```
docker run -d --name mysql57 -p 3306:3306 \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=db_name \
-v /path/to/your/dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql \
mysql:5.7
```

Comment: Yeah, I found that earlier too, but there is no file like `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` that I can reference to.

Comment: It's not a file, it's a directory in the container's filesystem root: `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. You have to put sql file for example there.

Comment: How can I access it on existing/running container from terminal? Is it even possible?

Comment: I really don't understand what do you mean, by mounting a volume when running a container you are sharing your local files with the container.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how to access `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` from outside terminal. Volume shows `/var/lib/mysql` so I basically have access to only those three folders (as far as I know at least).

Comment: I still don’t know what you are trying to access? You are supposed to mount your directory with sql files to that directory in the container. When it starts it will load all sql files stored inside that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the way: `docker exec -i some-mariadb mysql -uroot -pmy-secret-pw test < table.aktualnosci.sql` had to be imported first because it contains schema and after that I could import `data.aktualnosci.sql` when table with schema was created.

Thanks for Your patience. Just didn't know that data was separately dumped from data.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me ... can't thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

A docker image is built using a Dockerfile

I guess your comes from

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

or a variant like

https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

or

https://hub.docker.com/r/centurylink/mysql/

Anyway, you should use the Dockerfile, for example this one

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6c414e7f38c2079c7193beae5dc7c34ee46cd6e7/8.0/Dockerfile

and include some

ADD

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

or

COPY

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

commands in order to copy your .sql file to the right place.

Comment: So I can't do it from terminal or without creating Dockerfile?

Comment: I do not say that, docker comes with an easy process for modifying/creating docker images, I think this is the way to go. I guess you can do it from command line. For 1) is that directory available either because you did a `-v` or any other reason?